# No enclosing instance is in scope with double brace initializers

Tags: java, super, nested-class, array-initialization

I have some classes nested one in another

```
public abstract class I
{
    public abstract int f();
}

public class J
{
    private List<I> li;
    public J(List<I> l)
    {
        li = l;
    }
}

public class A // first class
{
    private int x; // field of A
    public class B extends J // second class
    {
        public B()
        {
            super(new ArrayList<I>() // super call
            {{ // array initializer
                add(new I() // third class
                {
                    @Override
                    public int f()
                    {
                        return x; // <- here!!!
                    }
                });
            }});
        }
    }
 }
```

Under these conditions, I get the error: "error: no enclosing instance of type A is in scope". Removing any element from this setup fixes this error. Also, taking x and saving it to another variable then using that variable also works.

What is happening here? It seems like a bug in a compiler for me.

Comment: You can declare `x` as `static` or `final` in order to fix the scope.

Comment: The double-brace hack is an antipattern, and you're better off just not using it.

Comment: It'd be better to use Arrays.asList than the double-brace hack. But it's not the issue here. The field x must be declared 1/ as final, either static or not, and with an initializer as it can't be initialized in the ctor of B before calling super(...) 2/ or as static

Answer (score 0):

It is not allowed to have 2 public classes in one Java File and file name should be same as public class name.

Comment: I know and this is completely off-topic.

Answer (score 0):

To experiment with your code I made a new `Test` class like this. I see no errors reported (using Java 8). Perhaps this is a build issue.

```
public class Test {

    public abstract class I {

        public abstract int f();
    }

    public class J {

        private List<I> li;

        public J(List<I> l) {
            li = l;
        }
    }

    public class A // first class
    {

        private int x; // field of A

        public class B extends J // second class
        {

            public B() {
                super(new ArrayList<I>() // super call
                {
                    { // array initializer
                        add(new I() // third class
                        {
                            @Override
                            public int f() {
                                return x; // <- here!!!
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }

    public void test() {
        System.out.println("Hello");
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="test">
        try {
            new Test().test();
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            t.printStackTrace(System.err);
        }
        //</editor-fold>
    }
}
```

Java 7 also seems to accept this code.